# Проблема с Сессией

Tags: php, сессия

Всем привет, есть ли способ убить сессию после закрытия вкладки в браузере? 
Например мой код

```
session_start();


if(isset($_SESSION['shaccesforadmpanhard']) && $_SESSION['shaccesforadmpanhard'] = TRUE) {
echo 'succes';

}

else {
    header("location:adminplace.php");
}

?>
```

Мне нужно , чтобы сессия открылась во время перехода на страницу , а после того как вкладку этой страницы закрыли, сессия умерла, пробовал session_destroy(); не особо помогло.

Comment: Вы в php не можете отследить закрытие вкладки. Можно session lifetime секунду поставить попробовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена, просто забыл поставить `session_unset();`

Вот конечный код, если кому-нибудь нужно:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['shaccesforadmpanhard']) && $_SESSION['shaccesforadmpanhard'] = TRUE) {
    echo 'succes';
} else {
    header("location:adminplace.php");
}
session_unset();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Возможности убить сессию после закрытия вкладки в браузере не предоставляется.

*Дополнения*: сессия автоматически удаляется после "неактивности" пользователя, стандартное время удаления сессии - 24 минуты.

Сервер самостоятельно не может определить работает ли пользователь с сайтом или уже закрыл, поэтому работает описанная выше суть.

Более подробную информацию про настройки сессии можете почитать [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/182352/), там все подробно расписано по сессиям.

Comment: А я сделал так , чтобы после закрытия вкладки сессия удалялась , код ниже поставил.

Comment: А при обновлении вкладки что происходит?